# Iterating on hash keys in perl

Tags: perl, loops, hash

I have a hash like below.

```
(
    'cars' => {
        'citroen' => {
            'sedan'    => { 'color' => 'red'   },
            'hatchback => { 'color' => 'white' },
            'truck'    => { 'color' => 'black' },
        },
        'ford' => {
            'sedan'    => { 'color' => 'red'   },
            'hatchback => { 'color' => 'white' },
            'truck'    => { 'color' => 'black' },
        },
    },
)
```

Car versions are sedan, hatchback and truck I want to get these versions and iterate over them. If sedan do.... If hatchback do...... If truck do....

I tried:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %{ $myhash->{'cars'}->{$carCompany} } ) { 
    print "\nCarVersion:" . $key;
}
```

But I couldn't get these versions.

Comment: I am not sure I understand..You want to find all car companies that have a sedan version, then all companies that have a hatchback version and so on?

Comment: lets say i dont know which versions each car company have. How can i get the versions. I will have a sub and when i give this hash to sub it will tell me ford company has sedan,hatchnack and truck versions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

```
foreach my $key (keys %{$myhash->{'cars'}->{'ford'}}) { print $key."\n"; }
```

this gives:

```
sedan
hatchback
truck
```

This was the output I wanted.